# A word that means the opposite of "shoehorned", something that fits its purpose well

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I'm looking for a word that means the opposite of *shoehorned*, ie. something that DOES fit its purpose well.

> **shoehorn** (*v.*) (*transitive, figuratively*) To force (something) into (a tight space); to squeeze (something) into (a schedule, etc); to exert great effort to insert or include (something); to include (something) despite potent reasons not to. - *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoehorn)*

Ideally not a compound word, like *well-suited*. *Appropriate* is close, but not quite.

Example:

> We will be judging on the following:
>
> 1. How *well-suited* the design is for the problem being solved.

Comment: What definition of "shoehorned" are you using?

Comment: "Used for a specific purpose even when not well suited"

Comment: Basically, "shoehorned" means "crammed" or "forced into".

Comment: Welcome to the site. I doubt that  @KillingTime wanted to start a discussion; their remark should be understood as a hint to revise your question to show the definition. Please read the site help/guide to see how to ask good questions.

Comment: Use your own solution, *well-suited*, bespoke, tailor-made, or fits-like-a-glove.

Comment: How ***appropriate*** the design is …  or the ***appropriateness*** of the design …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Fits like a glove' would be the appropriate phrase.

Therefore, '**suited**', I suggest.

> a. transitive. To be suitable or appropriate for (something); to be fitted or adapted to; to meet the requirements of.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193719?rskey=tFFgny&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

(One does not need the compound 'well-suited'. If a thing is suited, then it is *necessarily* a good fit.)

Comment: I guess *well-suited* arose as a contrast with *ill-suited*. But "suited" has various meanings in addition to "appropriate/fitted", such as "dressed in a suit", so "well-suited" has its place to avoid ambiguity: a suited man may not necessarily be well-suited for all events.